# How to use JWT in auth?

Tags: security, session, cookies, jwt

I have recently decided to review auth flows and available solutions for nowadays. Being simple, there are 2 options I'm interested in: **Sessions/Cookies** and **JWT**.

Let's check the 1st one. Sessions is "old but gold" technology, which is still widely in use for most server-based apps.

*Advantages of Sessions/Cookies*

- Easy to use
- Encrypted
- Protected against XSS attacks (with `httpOnly` flag)
- Protected against CSRF attacks (with `sameSite` flag)
- Easy to set expiration
- Easy to manage from server side by setting appropriate headers
- It's possible to scale using session store (e.g. redis)

*Disadvantages*

- Small size (4kb)
- Used in server-based apps and doesn't fit well to SPAs (Single Page Apps)
- Cross-domain requests issue
- Since many apps can use single API, it's hard to manage auth with sessions
- SSO (Single Sign On) - how to implement?
- Need additional server to store session data
- Need to query database for each request (to check user id)

So here in the modern world JWT came to solve the problems.

*Advantages of JWT*

- Secure by it's nature
- Stateless, good for any platform (web, mobile)
- Best fit for Restful APIs
- Widely used in SSO (Single Sign On)
- No need to query database on server side (to check user id), since token can contain immutable data
- Good to securely transfer data between parties, as it's impossible to forge data

*Disadvantages*

- Bigger in size
- Not easy to manage from server side
- Need manually send it with headers from client side

After a lot of reading on the topic, I still can't figure out how to deal with JWT properly. Let's talk about client side and how to store JWT.

Most people, I guess, find it easy to store JWT in `localStorage`, but of course this is a bad idea, since it's not secure and vulnerable for XSS attacks. Cookies? - Possible, I think, just cookies without setting up sessions, but have to struggle with cross-domain requests and not being CSRF vulnerable. Do you know the proper way to achieve this? I still have a big question - **Where to store?**

On the other hand, assume we have SPA, it's popular nowadays. From the [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#single-page-applications)

> **Single page applications**
>
> If you have a single page application (SPA) with no corresponding backend server, your SPA should request new tokens on page load and store them in memory without any persistence. To make API calls, your SPA would then use the in-memory copy of the token.

Does it mean I have to login and get token on every page refresh? - Come on, this is not the way. I want a user to stay signed in.

So back to server-side regular web apps with session/cookies? I personally prefer JWT, so what's the best way/flow to use JWT? I would appreciate any clear explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JWT is not secure by nature. It's not a good or secure standard. http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Regarding how to keep users logged in on a SPA, you can use a session just fine. Store the session key in a cookie, then send a REST API call to the backend to load the user/session data when the page is loaded.

Alternatively, use an authentication flow where you redirect the user to the ID server when they load the application. The ID server can then have a cookie set, and manage authentication, without the user needing to log in again. This is similar to the SPA solution you asked about, but the user won't notice it much.